# Empirical variance of simulation estimate

Tags: self-study, variance, estimation, inference, monte-carlo

Consider the following quantity of interest:

$$I[a,b]=\int_{a}^{b}g(\theta)h(\theta), \ldots (1)$$

that is, the expected value of some function $h(\theta)$, of $\theta$ distributed $g(\theta)$.

Suppose the probability function $g(\theta)$ is difficult to express. A substitute for analytically calculating equation $(1)$ is to randomly generate $n$ values of $\theta$ from  $g(\theta)$ and calculate:

$$\hat I[a,b]=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}h(\theta_i).$$
The empirical variance of the Monte Carlo simulation estimate is

$$Var(\hat I[a,b])=\frac{1}{n(n-1)}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(h(\theta_i)-\hat I[a,b])^2 \ldots (2)$$

I am not understanding  why there is the factor $n(n-1)$ in the denominator of the empirical variance of equation $(2)$ rather than simply $(n-1)$? Why there is $n$ multiplied with $(n-1)$?

Comment: $I[a, b]$ is the expected value only if $supp(g)\subseteq [a,b]$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably confusing the estimator $\widehat{var(h)}$ for the variance with the variance $Var(\hat I)$ of the estimator $\hat I$ of the mean.

One popular estimator of the variance
$$
\widehat{var(h)} = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n(h_i - \hat I)^2
$$
contains, indeed, the factor $(n-1)$ in the denominator.

But, in general, the [variance of the estimator of the mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error#Standard_error_of_the_mean) $\mu_h$ of any random variable $h$ is $\frac{\sigma^2_h}{n}$. Thus, the source of your formula has chosen to take as estimator of the variance the estimator of the variance divided by $n$:
$$
\begin{align}
Var(\hat I) &= \frac{1}{n} \widehat{var(h)}\\
            &= \frac{1}{n(n-1)} \sum_{i=1}^n(h_i - \hat I)^2.
\end{align}
$$